# reverse mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql

I have a piece of data that is large and will probably contain quotes and double quotes.

I'm using `mysql_real_escape_string()` to store it safely.

When I pull it out to look at it, all the quotes are escaped. I tried using `str_replace` to just get rid of all the quotes, but that turns `\r\n`'s into `rn`. :(

How can I reverse it so the data comes back out the way it went in?

Comment: Useful question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you use magic quotes?

> Note: If magic_quotes_gpc is enabled,
>   first apply stripslashes() to the
>   data. Using this function [mysql_real_escape_string] on data
>   which has already been escaped will
>   escape the data twice.

Answer (score 10):

Who says?

```
$keyword = "TEST'TEST";

$result1 = mysql_real_escape_string($keyword);
echo $result1 --> TEST\'TEST

$result2 = nl2br(stripslashes($result));
echo $result2 --> TEST'TEST
```

Comment: After escaping string, your string can become "TEST \r\n \'TEST", in that case nl2br will not work. So I did something like this:
stripslashes(str_replace('\r\n' , '<br/>' , nl2br( "TEST \r\n \'TEST")))

Answer (score 2):

If you actually want to reverse that because of how your data is formatted, this is a solution I came up with:

```
function mysql_unreal_escape_string($string) {
    $characters = array('x00', 'n', 'r', '\\', '\'', '"','x1a');
    $o_chars = array("\x00", "\n", "\r", "\\", "'", "\"", "\x1a");
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
        if (substr($string, $i, 1) == '\\') {
            foreach ($characters as $index => $char) {
                if ($i <= strlen($string) - strlen($char) && substr($string, $i + 1, strlen($char)) == $char) {
                    $string = substr_replace($string, $o_chars[$index], $i, strlen($char) + 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $string;
}
```